# Using monolog and whoops

Tags: php, exception, monolog, whoops

I am trying to using Monolog in the `set_exception_handler` and `set_error_handler`, while Whoops outside.

I tried 2 locations for running Whoops.

1. `Run Whoops #1 Location`

   - Result: Monolog logs the error/exception and Whoops doesn't display
2. `Run Whoops #2 Location`

   - Result: Monolog doesn't log anything and Whoops displays

I am stuck on why I am not able to get both Monolog and Whoops to work together.

```
...
use Whoops\Run;
use Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//Run Whoops #1 Location
$whoops = new Run();
$whoops->prependHandler(new PrettyPageHandler());
$whoops->register();

function exceptionHandler($e)
{ 
    //log the exception using monolog
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    //log the error using monolog
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');

//Run Whoops #2 Location
```

Answer (score 0):

The *set_exception_handler* function in php is overridden by the Whoops library. We can use the Whoops library's *pushHandler* method to register a generic handler function, and initialise Monolog inside of that function:

```
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$whoops->pushHandler(function($exception, $inspector, $run) {

   // Initialise Monolog here. Example with stack trace support:
    $formatter = new LineFormatter(
        LineFormatter::SIMPLE_FORMAT, 
        LineFormatter::SIMPLE_DATE
    );
    $formatter->includeStacktraces(true);
    $errlog = new Logger('Error Log');
    $stream = new StreamHandler("logs/error.log", Logger::ERROR);
    $stream->setFormatter($formatter);
    $errlog->pushHandler($stream);
    $errlog->error($exception);

    return Handler::DONE;       
});
```